# questions about tableless column for ActiveRecord

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have a question about ActiveRecord hope any of you can help me a bit. Thanks in advance :).

I have a ActiveRecord model which has a boolean field to indicate whether the use has accepted the license. I don't want to create a database column related to that but I would like it to consume all the validation stuff and type conversion provided by ActiveRecord. There are lots of solutions on the web but all of them are focusing on tableless model (e.g., http://railscasts.com/episodes/193-tableless-model), while my model also have other fields corresponding to table columns. Here is what I come up with:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  include TablelessColumns

  tableless_column :license_accepted, :boolean

  # other fields that are corresponding to table columns
end

module TablelessColumns
  def self.included(base)
    base.extend(ClassMethods)
  end

  module ClassMethods
    def tableless_columns
      read_inheritable_attribute(:tableless_columns)
    end

    def tableless_column(name, sql_type = nil, default = nil, null = true)
      write_inheritable_attribute(:tableless_columns, {}) if tableless_columns.nil?
      tableless_columns[name] = ActiveRecord::ConnectionAdapters::Column.new(name.to_s, default, sql_type.to_s, null)

      define_method("#{name.to_s}=".to_sym) { |value| instance_variable_set(to_variable(name), value) }
      define_method(name) { self.class.tableless_columns[name].type_cast(instance_variable_get(to_variable(name))) }
    end
  end

  def to_variable(sym)
    "@#{sym.to_s}".to_sym
  end
end
```

This solution seems pretty verbose and I am wondering whether there are better ones out there.

Answer (score 3):

I think I saw it in some authentication plugin for sending password confirmation to model without saveing it to db, so you can just add to your model:

```
attr_accessor :accepted_license
```

And now you can use it with validations and forms.